# Cron expression to run on first Tuesday of the month, Tuesday should be followed by a Monday

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

I want to schedule a lambda function to run on first Tuesday every month. But the Tuesday should be followed by Monday.
Ex:
Aug 1: Tuesday -> Lambda shouldn't get invoked
Aug 7: Monday, Aug 8: Tuesday -> Lambda should be invoked
I am not able to figure out the cron expression for the same.
Any leads would be helpful!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't do that with a simple cron expression. Your better option is to run the function every Tuesday of every week, and have code in the function to check if it is the "first Tuesday in the month following a Monday" and just exit if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your problem you can say that you need to execute the lambda the day after the first monday of the month, every month.
one option would be to execute the Lambda on the last minute of the first monday of the month.

`cron(59 23 ? * 2#1 *)`

Also if you use AWS event bridge schedules there is a flexible time windows.

If this doesn't work for you, it will be necessary to create a lambda to handle this logic, the AWS cron expression does not support this logic out of the box.